# C++ How to change windows tray notification balloon icon? (information icon)

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, trayicon, popup-balloons

I'd like to change tray notify icon with user customized icon.   I have already searched on the internet, but I can't find where a solution is.   If my problem is duplicated, please send me a reference link.

**Steps:**

I have tried this using `NOTIFYICONDATAW .hIcon & .hBalloonIcon`.  A part of implementation below.

**Implementation:**

```
NOTIFYICONDATAW nt = {0};
nt.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATAW);
nt.hWnd = GetSafeHwnd();
nt.uID = IDR_MAINFRAME;

nt.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_INFO;
nt.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_INFO;
nt.uCallbackMessage = WM_TRAY_NOTIFY;
nt.hIcon = theApp.LoadIconW(IDR_MAINFRAME);
nt.hBalloonIcon = theApp.LoadIconW(IDR_MAINFRAME);

...

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nt);
```

But unfortunately, still I got same (information) icon on the balloon notification.

**Environment:**

MFC Dialog Based, Win 10 x64.

Is it possible to change balloon icon?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run your program as administrator ?

Comment: @nakE, I tried to run application as administrator, but it is the same.

Comment: It's definitely possible, I did it very recently. You just need to set the appropriate flags. It is also adequately documented by Microsoft. Basically caused by the `NIIF_INFO` flag (causing an info icon to be displayed). Try 0 (none) or `NIIF_USER`, possibly in combination with `NIIF_LARGE_ICON`. You may also need to perform a 2nd call to `Shell_NotifyIcon()`, to set the version to `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4`.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou, Thank you very much! I solved it. If you post your answer, I will vote up your post. I used `nt.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_USER | NIIF_LARGE_ICON`